# Insert in mysql from html table with array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i  search a lot on Stack, try with couple of examples, but no result. Question is probably duplicate, but no one of examples work for me...

So, here is my html page, row.html

```
<form  id="calx" method="POST" action="obrada.php">
<script>
function addRow(tableID) { 

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var paki= rowCount+1;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name="chkbox[]";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='broj_oper[]' value='"+paki+"'>";

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  name='oper[]' />";


        }
</script>

     <td><INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /></td>
  <tr>
<td>

<TABLE width="425" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="40" align="center"></th>
<th width="94">Broj operacije</th>
<th width="121">Operacija</th>


</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="dataTable">

</tbody>
</TABLE>
```

/** PLEASE DON'T TAKE A CARE OF HTML, this is just a part of huge page,and it is all fine **/

I use Js+Html form to create dinamic table,and it work realy good.

Now, on page obrada.php, i use this part of code for insert data into database :

```
$materijal_upis = $connection->db->prepare("INSERT INTO operacije (id,prva,druga,treca,cetvrta) VALUES ('',?,?,?,?)  ");
                $materijal_upis ->bind_param('ssss',$prva,$druga,$treca,$cetvrta);
                $materijal_upis->execute();
```

Now, problem is here:

I need to post oper[] from rows.html to obrada.php and store values in this order:

```
 oper[0]=>$prva
 oper[1]=>$druga
 oper[2]=>$treca
 oper[3]=>$cetvrta
```

I guess it is a smiple solution, but I am without ideas :)

Tnx,
P

Comment: Do you get a error message? Is Id column `AUTO INCREMENT`?

Comment: Hi Kay,tnx for time, first of all, I must solve problem with values from oper[]. I try with foreach loop, but can't get values in order that i write in code... Yeah, ID is autoincrement column...

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `serialize()` before form sending.

```
var From = $('form').serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolve:

Array preparing:

```
  $array = $_POST['oper'];
$zarez = implode("','", $array);
echo $konacno = "'".$zarez."'";
```

SQL :

```
$materijal_upis = $connection->db->prepare('INSERT INTO operacije (prva,druga,treca,cetvrta) VALUES ('.$konacno.')  ');

                $materijal_upis->execute();
```

Tnx all!